# What does the role and line_spoken do in code?

Tags: python

What does the role, and line_spoken do? I have made a print but I am not getting. Glad if anyone can help me out to what does role and line_spoken do?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

man =[]
other=[]

f=open("passwd")
for line in f:
    try:
        (role, line_spoken)= line.split(":",1)
        print role
        #print line_spoken
    except:
        print "File missing"
```

Comment: What is the content of `passwd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called tuple unpacking.

```
a, b = 1, 2
print a # 1
print b # 2
```

`line.split(...)` returns two elements which get unpacked to `role`, `line_spoken`.

So, for example if `line.split(...)` returns `['Monty', 'Python']`, `role` would get `'Monty'` and `line_spoken` would get `'Python'`.